# Checking for valid email and if it exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully been able to allow users to invite a friend by sending them an email with a unique invite code,

- however I am trying to add to ability to check if it is a valid email address and if the email is already registered in another table 'users' (same database) as it would be a headache for someone who is already registered to receive invite emails.

I have tried to check for a valid email and if it exists by writing this script:

```
  function email_registered($email) {
  $email = sanitize($email);
  return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   '$email'"), 0)  ==1) ? true : false;
}      


    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
    }
    if (email_registered($_POST['email']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use';
    }
```

This was successful for checking emails addresses when registering a user but registering a account was in the same table as already registered account. I am unsure how to use the same script in the invite code as I am trying to check an email in the registered separate table.

Currently it does not check if it is a valid email or if it exists.

The Full PHP:

```
include 'config.php';

function email_registered($email) {
$email = sanitize($email);
return (mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT mysqli_num_rows()(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0)  ==1) ? true : false;
} 


if(!empty($_POST)){
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);         

    $length = 10;
    $inviteCode = "";
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $inviteCode .= $characters[mt_rand(10, strlen($characters))];
    }

function email_registered($email)
{
    if (!empty($email)) {
        $ret_val = false;

        $query = sprintf(
            "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '%s'",
            mysqli_real_escape_string($email)
        );

        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            //email exists
            ?> 
            <p>User Exists</p>
            <?php 

            $ret_val = true;
        } else {
            $query = sprintf(
                "SELECT id FROM invites WHERE email = '%s'",
                mysqli_real_escape_string($email)
            );

            $result = mysqli_query($query);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                //email exists
                ?>
                <p>User Exists</p>
                <?php

                $ret_val = true;
            }
        }
        return $ret_val;
    }
 }

else { 

     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `referrals` (`email`, `inviteCode`) VALUES   ('$email', '$inviteCode') "); }
     //you might want to consider checking more here such as $query == true as it can return other statuses that you may not want
     if($query){ 

  include 'userinvite.php';

     ?>
         <p> "Thank you for inviting your friends!"</p>
     <?php 

    }
    else{
    ?>
       <p>Sorry there must have been a problem</p>
    <?php
        die('Error querying database. ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
else {
?>
    <p>Please enter an email</p>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

I am just trying to check if the email is registered in the 'users' table and if the email entered is a valid email.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). While it's unlike something actually could get in because of the email validation you're doing, it's still not a good idea to hope that this will always not be the case.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, sorry :( Can you expand on your question? Explain what you're trying to achieve in addition to providing all of the code above.

Comment: @Kita I have updated the post, I am trying to check if the email entered is a valid email address and if it exists in another table.

Comment: Are you connected to database? Doesn't seem to be the case in your `Full PHP`, also we would need to see `email_exists`. If you are not connected to the database your code will stop executing after the 2nd line.

Comment: I have updated the post again, I am connected to the database as the referral table adds a column for the already registered. The column should not be added with a invite code if it already registered in the other 'users' table.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, *by the way*. They do **not** mix together. `return (mysql_result(mysql_query` and `mysqli_query` etc. Choose "one" not two.

Comment: ^--< Most probable cause - *"Currently it does not check if it is a valid email or if it exists."*

Comment: Another thing, [`sanitize()`](http://ca3.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sanitize&scope=quickref), isn't a core PHP function; or do you have a function for it? If not, change `$email = sanitize($email);` to `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: *"if the email is already registered in another table 'users'"* - Use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead of `COUNT()` - You're overthinking this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have a function for sanatize. Most of my functions are defined in files that are included at the top of the page that was used for the login and register scripts. So what should the line `(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   '$email'"), 0)  ==1) ? true : false; ` be for a mysqli_query, because replacing mysql_query with mysqli_query creates an undefined function for mysql_result / mysql_result.

Comment: You'll need to either use **all** `mysql_` functions or **all** `mysqli_`. So, you'll need to replace all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_`, again, you can **not** mix MySQL APIs, which is the reason you're getting errors, as you stated in your comment *"creates an undefined function for mysql_result / mysql_result"*

Comment: I noticed your edit `SELECT mysqli_num_rows()` that wasn't what I meant about using `mysqli_num_rows()`. It is to be used in a conditional statement like this, `$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE column='$variable'";` then do `$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query); if($numrows > 0){ // exists }` - What Kita posted below, should work, where changing all `mysql_` to `mysqli_`, with a few modifications of course. Or, `SELECT column1, column2 from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main question is how to check if an email exists in another table. If that's wrong, let me know and I can update my answer :P Here's a rough draft of a function you should be able to use.

I'm assuming you have these two tables:

Table 1: users

```
||id||email||name||
```

Table 2: invites

```
||id||email||inviter_user_id||
```

You can use this function to check if the email exists in either table

```
<?php
    /**
     * Check if the given email already exists in the DB
     *
     * @param $email string the email to check
     */
    function email_exists($email)
    {
        if (!empty($email)) {
            $ret_val = false;

            $query = sprintf(
                "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '%s'",
                mysqli_real_escape_string($email)
            );

            $result = mysqli_query($query);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                //email exists
                $ret_val = true;
            } else {
                $query = sprintf(
                    "SELECT id FROM invites WHERE email = '%s'",
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($email)
                );

                $result = mysqli_query($query);
                $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($num_rows > 0) {
                    //email exists
                    $ret_val = true;
                }
            }
            return $ret_val;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_*` functions, which is probably why OP may be experiencing problems with your answer.

Comment: This function should be used in the code that validates the invitation logic. When a user invites someone, they should be presented with an error if the user already exists in the system or if the user has already been invited. You should use a slightly modified version of this function when validating registering users since they shouldn't get an error if their email matches an invitation email.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I updated my answer. The original post I saw had a mix of mysql and mysqli functions.

Comment: @Kita OP seems to be having difficulties and looks like is in a learning stage, therefore it only makes it harder for all of us to provide a full working solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I apologise for lack of understanding, I can imagine how frustrating that would be. Thank you for your input, I have more understanding using mysqli & mysql functions (Y) I have updated the original post to what the script currently looks like whist messing with. Still not receiving any output messages or preventing table input is exists.

Comment: @Kita thank you for your time and input, I apologise for not quite understanding. I have updated the original post, and this post has helped my understanding of mysql & mysql functions. I have still yet to get any messages to appear or prevent table input, but still messing with it.

Comment: @JSK Don't worry about it, and you're welcome ;-) If I get some free time, I'll see what I can do to put something together for you. Till then, try and go over each of your functions one step at a time. Don't try to put all the ingredients in your soup at the same time, hoping it will taste good ;-) (*Just another of my silly analogies*)

Comment: @JSK You're welcome. Hopefully my answer will get you going in the right direction :)

Comment: @JSK I see you've accepted Kita's answer. Everything good I take it?